# PHP not inserting no errors

Tags: php, pdo

I have hit a brick wall on trying to figure out why this code will insert sometimes and other times it won't. There are no error messages or error logs.

The code logic is if the email record is in the email table then it then it will get the id and insert into the customer table. If email is not found then it will insert into email table then customer.

```
<?php

/* Default */

$terms               =  $_POST['terms'];
$ipAddress        = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

/* Database conections */

include 'config.php';

try
{
    $conn   =   new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$config['dataBaseName'], $config['userName'], $config['password']);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Connection failded' . $e->getMessage();
}


/* Post data */


if (isset($_POST["firstName"]))
{
       $firstName = trim(ucfirst($_POST["firstName"]));
}

if (isset($_POST["email"]))
{
       $email = trim(ucfirst($_POST["email"]));
}

if (isset($_POST["postCode"]))
{
       $postCode = trim(strtoupper($_POST["postCode"]));
}

if (isset($_POST["url"]))
{
        $url      =  trim(ucfirst($_POST["url"]));
}
if (isset($_POST["terms"]))
{
        $terms     =  trim(ucfirst($_POST["terms"]));
}


/* Check if email is in database returns array */

try
{

echo 'Finding Email ->' .$email;

$stmt   = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,email FROM email WHERE email = :email");
$stmt->bindParam(':email',$email);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}

catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Check if email is in table' . $e->getMessage();
}


/* Insert Logic + functions */


try
{

if(empty($result)  or is_null($result))
{
    /* Insert into email table */
    $stmt   = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO email (`email`) values(:email)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':email',$email);
    $stmt->execute();
    /* grab id from email table */

    $stmt   = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM email WHERE email = :email");
    $stmt->bindParam(':email',$email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result =  $result["id"];   

    /* insert into customer table */

    $stmt   = $conn->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO customer (`emailid`, `firstname`, `postcode`, `terms`, `browser`, `ipaddress`)
         VALUES(:emailid, :firstname, :postcode,  :terms, :browser, :ipaddress)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':emailid',$result);
        $stmt->bindParam(':firstname',$firstName);
        $stmt->bindParam(':postcode',$postCode);
        $stmt->bindParam(':terms',$terms);
        $stmt->bindParam(':browser',$url);
        $stmt->bindParam(':ipaddress',$ipAddress);
        $stmt->execute();
}
else
{
    /* grabs id from email table */

    $stmt   = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM email WHERE email = :email");
    $stmt->bindParam(':email',$email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result =  $result["id"];   

    /* insert into customer table */

    $stmt   = $conn->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO customer (`emailid`, `firstname`, `postcode`,  `terms`, `browser`, `ipaddress`)
         VALUES(:emailid, :firstname, :postcode, :terms, :browser, :ipaddress)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':emailid',$result);
        $stmt->bindParam(':firstname',$firstName);
        $stmt->bindParam(':postcode',$postCode);
        $stmt->bindParam(':terms',$terms);
        $stmt->bindParam(':browser',$url);
        $stmt->bindParam(':ipaddress',$ipAddress);
        $stmt->execute();     
}


$conn->commit();


}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Insert error -->' . $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

Comment: If you want to see errors. Add this code `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: Could you define "sometimes" a little better? Is it completely random, or only with certain input?

Comment: You create all your variables, like: `$firstName` inside `if`-statements, but further down in your insert, you just take for granted that they exists.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson there is a lot more wrong with this code, but I do not see any reason why a record would not be inserted.

Comment: @BartFriederichs - Sure, but we need to start somewhere

Comment: @MagnusEriksson we don't have to start [a forum-like discussion]. "Online debugging" is prohibited by the rules. Either the question is answerable or it should be closed.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - Fair enough.. .

Comment: @BartFriederichs it is completely random.

Comment: how do you know there was no insert?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson could you elaborate please

Comment: There will be no error logs **because you deliberately made it so.** Get rid of all the try..catch stuff, tell PHP to log errors and *then* check error logs.

Comment: @YourCommonSense after the form has been submitted I've checked the database and the record wasn't in there.

Comment: it cannot be. either there is an error or the insert is successful.

Comment: @YourCommonSense removed the try catch and now getting errors, insert still goes through though.                                                                             [13-Nov-2016 11:17:05 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'There is no active transaction' in formSubmit.php:114
Stack trace:
#0 formSubmit.php(114): PDO->commit()
#1 {main}
  thrown in formSubmit.php on line 114

Comment: Just remove the commit call. it's irrelevant though. Wait for the insert that fails and than check the logs

Comment: No errors in log not sure why this has been marked as duplicate.